question about indices of symmetric bilinear form
Suppose $f$ is a symmetric bilinear form over an $n$-dimensional real vector space $V$ and $f$ has rank $r$ (the rank of $f$ is the rank of the matrix $(a_{ij})$ of a representation of $f$ once a base for $V$ is chosen, so if that base is $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$, $a_{ij}=f(e_i,e_j)$).
There exists $0\leq p \leq r$, $p$ only depending on $f$, and a base of $V$ so that the quadratic form $q$ associated with $f$ becomes $q=x_1^2+\ldots+x_p^2-x_{p+1}^2-\ldots-x_r^2$ $\ $(this basically is Sylvester's law). Now, I can show that $p$, called the positivity index, is the maximum dimension of a subspace $W$ for which $q(w)>0, \forall w \in W, w\neq 0$ and similarly $r-p$, called the negativity index, is the maximum dimension of a subspace $W$ for which $q(w)<0, \forall w \in W, w\neq 0$.
Apparently, $n-r$, called the nullity index, is the maximum dimension of a subspace $W$ for which $q(w)=0, \forall w \in W$. Of course there exists such a subspace of dimension $n-r$ (namely $<e_{r+1},\ldots,e_n>$), but how can one show that this is the maximal dimension of such a subspace?

You should state you are working over $\mathbb R$ otherwise a lot of the things stated don't work.  I don't understand your final paragraph.  Consider a non-degenerate indefinite form ($r=n$).  It will have a positive dimensional subspace where the form is totally isotropic ($q(w)=0$ for all $w\in W$) but $n-r=0$ which contradicts your assertion.  E.g. with $A=\left[\begin{matrix}0 & 1\1 &0\end{matrix}\right]$

It's literally a statement out of a math book, Lectures on Geometry by Badescu (page 97). A mistake thus.
